# JS button does not do anything when clicked when I call it using document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I'm trying to prevent me from accidentally deleting a user with an "are you sure?" step in between I click the delete button and it actually goes to the page that does the delete process.

My script is in php and I wanted to add the "are you sure" step in JS.

I've set a button:

```
<a href='/perfil/borrarUsuario.php?usuario=$userID' data-confirm='GASP! Esta seguro de querer hacer esto?' class='confirmarBorrar'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>BORRAR USUARIO</button></a>
```

I have a js file that I use to put all the bits of JS that I add to the site. It's called at the very bottom of every page, after all other JS libraries files that I may call (like jQuery).

I've added this to the file:

```
var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.confirmarBorrar');

for (var i = 0; i < deleteLinks.length; i++) {
  deleteLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var choice = confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm'));

    if (choice) {
      window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
    }
  });
}
```

I've added a demo at [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjKVab), and it does work there, but at my site it completely avoids the JS call, and goes directly to the delete script.

The console does not say anything, it's blank, and I've checked that the JS file is being properly called at the end of the html page.

What could be wrong?

### UPDATE:

I've checked that the JS was being called and it was being called ok. It is at the very end of the `<body>` tag.

**The only way that I do get it working is when I add the script between `<script>` tags right after the button, inserted into the php file (I know, that's not ok).**

What I'm thinking is that there is something in my .js file that's preventing that particular piece of script to work.

The file is +500 lines of code though and what I've done there is add several js functions. But I'm using `"use strict";` as the first line of code. I've commented that line and it still won't work.

The only workaround is actually inserting the code right after the button.

Comment: Add a `console.log(deleteLinks)`call just below the variable to see what results it found when it runs and one inside the addEventListener to verify that it runs on click.

Comment: A `<button>` is not allowed as a child element of `<a>` -> [W3C: 4.5.1 The `a` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Comment: You really should NOT delete a record with a GET request

Comment: Check where is your js code placed in html document. I suppose it's in `<head>`, or at the beggining of <body> where your `.confirmarBorrar` buttons weren't loaded in DOM yet. Try to put your script right before </body>

Comment: I've added that @Marie, and the console shows this: `NodeList [ <a.confirmarBorrar> ]`